# Subgroup generated by x,y s.t x and y are order 2

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

If $G$ is an Abelian group and $x,y \in G$ are elements of order two with $x \neq y$, prove that $H:=\langle x,y\rangle$ is of order 4 (that is , $H=\{1,x,y,xy\}$). Then, show that $H$ is isomorphic to $V_{4}$.

Comment: @mdave16 i first just tried saying that $x,y \in H$ obviously, so $x \cdot x, y \cdot y, x \cdot y \in H$, but $x\cdot x=1 = y \cdot y$ so all we will have is $x \cdot y$ out of those, but that didn't feel very rigorous to me. Didn't know how to proceed with showing $H \cong V_{4}$, however.

Comment: it is still rigorous :P (correctly written ofc) how do you define $V_4$? Also you should edit the question to reflect new information given in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\langle x,y \rangle = \{ e, x, y, xy \}$ since $$x^{2n}=y^{2n}=e$$ for $n\geq 0$ and $\langle x,y \rangle$ commutes under the operation of $G$, causing any elements of order $\geq 2$ to reduce to one already in our set. The set $V_4$ is defined to be
$$V_4 =\langle \alpha, \beta \ | \  \alpha^2=\beta^2=(\alpha \beta)^2 = e\rangle $$
So the mapping $\varphi: \langle x,y \rangle \to V_4$ defined by 
$$\varphi(a)=\alpha, \qquad \varphi(b)=\beta,$$
forced under the homomorphism condition is an isomorphism.